# Writing code that accounts/ignores errors or {}

Tags: warning-messages

An issue I seem to consistently be bumping into is getting errors from empty data sets {}, resulting in errors when I apply functions to them.

For example, I produce a dataset from a function where: `data={{3,2,5},{2,3,15},{2,23,24},{}}`

However, when I apply a function, such as `Transpose`, it will produce an error, which essentially makes the remaining functions I apply to it useless:

```
Transpose[data[[#]] & /@ {1, 2, 3, 4}]
```

My question is, what method should I take to make it so when I receive a `{}` string of data, it is excluded from the remainder of the script?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `data = DeleteCases[data, {}]` could work, if you don't need to know that there are these cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{3, 2, 5}, {2, 3, 15}, {2, 23, 24}, {}};

Transpose[data /. {} :> Sequence[]]
```

> {{3, 2, 2}, {2, 3, 23}, {5, 15, 24}}

There is no reason to use the more complicated

```
Transpose[data[[#]] & /@ {1, 2, 3, 4}]
```